# Although file exists im getting the error "OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2" in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, wav

I'm trying to transform a wav sound file to spech using Google Cloud API service.

The part that is not working is when I try to upload the wav file. Before sending it to transcription. I make this upload using this function:

```
File(path).readAsBytesSync().toList()
```

Although path is correct, the file temp.wav exists , when I try to upload it on my android device the system throws the error: OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_speech/speech_client_authenticator.dart';
import 'package:google_speech/google_speech.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:loading_indicator/loading_indicator.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        fontFamily: 'poppins',
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool is_Transcribing = false;
  String content = '';

  void transcribe() async {
    setState(() {
      is_Transcribing = true;
    });
    final serviceAccount = ServiceAccount.fromString(
        '${(await rootBundle.loadString('assets/adroit-arcana-360318-c441ebd23f86.json'))}');
    final speechToText = SpeechToText.viaServiceAccount(serviceAccount);

    final config = RecognitionConfig(
        encoding: AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        model: RecognitionModel.basic,
        enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
        sampleRateHertz: 16000,
        languageCode: 'en-US');

    final audio = await _getAudioContent();
    await speechToText.recognize(config, audio).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        content = value.results.map((e) => e.alternatives.first.transcript).join('\n');
      });
    }).whenComplete(() {
      setState(() {
        is_Transcribing = false;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<List<int>> _getAudioContent() async {
    //final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    //final path = directory.path + '/$name';
    //final path = '/sdcard/Download/temp.wav';
    final path = '/assets/sounds/temp.wav';
    return File(path).readAsBytesSync().toList();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    setPermissions();
    super.initState();
  }

  void setPermissions() async {
    await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    await Permission.storage.request();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 108, 96, 225),
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 80,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 108, 96, 225),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Transcribe Your Audio'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(50),
              topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 70,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: content == ''
                      ? Text(
                          'Your text will appear here',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        )
                      : Text(
                          content,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: is_Transcribing
                      ? Expanded(
                          child: LoadingIndicator(
                            indicatorType: Indicator.ballPulse,
                            colors: [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.blue],
                          ),
                        )
                      : ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            elevation: 10,
                            primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 108, 96, 225),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: is_Transcribing ? () {} : transcribe,
                          child: is_Transcribing
                              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                              : Text(
                                  'Transcribe',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here the

```
pubspec.yaml
```

```
name: flutter_transcribe
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_speech: ^2.0.1
  permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2
  loading_indicator: ^3.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/sounds/temp.wav
    - assets/sample.mp3
    - assets/sounds/giuseppebrandi.png
    - assets/adroit-arcana-360318-c441ebd23f86.json
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  fonts:
    - family: poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
```

[image: here's the file structure and the temp.wav file location]

- tried all similar errors (some have answers) but none of it solved the problem
- Invalidate cache/restart
- Put all the assets in the pubspec.yaml folder (with the correct sintax)
- Tried different types of files (including mp3)
- Tried a different android phone
- Changed the location of the file
- ran flutter doctor and nothing is wrong.

Since I don't know what to try next im seeking for help.

Comment: Use File.exists() and File.canRead() before you call your upload code. And tell full path.

Comment: File.exists() returns false, does not help much

Comment: Please tell full path that you used for File.exists(). Tell us value of File.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: File.exists('assets/sounds/temp.wav'), tried with absolute path (from my computer) but didnt work as well. I didnt find this dart function getabsolutepath. The file is inside my assets folder, inside the app

Comment: That is an impossible non existing path on an Android device. Of course you also cannot use a path from your pc.

Comment: If you did put a file in assets directory of your project on your pc then at runtime your app should use AssetsManager to open an input stream for your file in assets resource.

Comment: that was it. It solved the problem